# Combine scripts to reduce HTTP requests -- Invasion Of The Body Switchers

Tags: javascript

I'm using the Invasion Of The Body Switchers script (http://www.brothercake.com/site/resources/scripts/iotbs/) as a styleswitcher. This requires loading three js files in the header.

I'm trying to reduce HTTP requests by combining scripts when possible. Has anybody used IOTBS before and successfully combined the scripts into one file? Would I need to make any modifications to the scripts or to the HTML switchers on the page to make that work?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to pay attention to is the global namespace. IOTBS uses one global variable: `switcher`. Since these files are working together, then it is safe to consolidate them into one file. When you're consolidating them, please add them to the file in the order that they are called on the page.

And kudos for deciding to reduce HTTP requests. You're making the Internet a faster place.

Comment: "Usually safe". See my comment on David's answer. Also, with HTTP *pipelining* the multiple requests are not as a big of a deal as they once were, and there are minimal in light of other things: I would say the *more important* things are *caching* and *compression*.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put the three scripts into your HTML header in a row and it all loads properly, then you should be able to just concatenate the files together and load them with one script tag.

Separate script tags in HTML does *not* imply separate namespaces for the code inside.

Comment: However, make sure that the file are joined with a `;` as a precaution against the first line in subsequent files starting with a `(` (or verify such is not the case manually). Also, this approach may not work with systems (e.g ASP.NET) that have a "I'm done notification" such as `notifyScriptLoaded` in ASP.NET.

Comment: And no trailing ``;`` in the previous file. Yeah, I hadn't thought about that because I hate automatically-inserted semicolons and try to have them explicit in my code.